# How to create multiple relationships between the same two tables in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a Users table and a Reviews table.  The Reviews Table has ReviewedUserId and ReviewerUserId, both foreign keys that are pointing to the primary key of User table (UserId).  When I try to create the second relationship in Access between the User table and Reviews table, it creates a second User table and names in Users_1.

Firstly, is this normal in Access?  In SQl Server, I can have two relationships between two tables with no problem.

Secondly, is it possible to rename this alias table so that it doesn't have to be called Users_1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

User_1, User_2 etc is the way Access aliases tables when creating multiple relationships. If you use code to create the relationships, you can choose your own names

[Database.CreateRelation Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221012%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

But I do not know of any way to change the alias in the relationship window.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to have referential integrity enforced at the table level? Can you just set up the relationships as a query? I'd guess that you can rename the 'alias' table if you do it via a query. In fact, you could just write the SQL and paste it right into an MS Access query.

I very rarely set up table level relationships in Access nowadays, and I also rarely even link forms through directly to tables or queries any more. I use unbound forms, populate them with code, and use code / DAO to control the updates of the relevant recordsets. All the behaviour of relationships, I then enact using SQL & VB as required.

Comment: Thanks, I ended going this route this time.